# ActionScript NetStream.Publish.BadName Error after Connection lost

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, actionscript, red5

I'm using AS3 and Red5 Flash Server for streaming.

Everything worked fine until I've got an issue. I don't know its Flash server bug or not !

When i close a stream connection (on publisher) and connect it again its worked, but **when i disconnect my internet connection (for testing) then reconnect and refresh page, it gave me :** `NetStream.Publish.BadName` in EventListener.

I googled it and found it happened when there is  an existing publishing client that they forget to close and then they try to run another one. Only one publisher can use a unique name at a time.

So when i lost my network connection, my publisher name is still in the server and i can't use that name again till server restarted !

Is it a Zombie Stream process? 
How can i close idle stream names or close them manually?

Sorry for bad English.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Looks like this is a known issue with Red5: http://code.google.com/p/red5/issues/detail?id=325

Comment: Thanks alot, So what can i do ?

Answer (score 0):

https://helpx.adobe.com/adobe-media-server/kb/prevent-netstream-publish-badname-errors.html

Issue

Flash Media Server returns a NetStream.Publish.BadName message to a publisher. The error occurs when there is a disruption in the connection to the server and the publisher tries to republish the live stream.
Solution

Configure the application's PublishTimeout value to allow Flash Media Server to clear the first publishing connection and allow the subsequent publishing connection to take over the live stream. The PublishTimeout setting specifies the time (in milliseconds) the server waits for a response from a publisher when another client tries to publish to the stream. If the first publisher fails to respond within the time specified in this tag, the server allows the second publisher to take over the live stream. The default value is 2000 (or 2 seconds), follow these steps to change it:

```
Edit the local or global Application.xml. The default global location is in $fms_root\conf\_defaultRoot_\_defaultVHost_..
Change numerical value between the Application > StreamManager >  Live > PublishTimeout  tags.
Save the file and restart the application.
```

Notes:

```
Disable this tag by setting the value to -1.
For streams experiencing latency, consider increasing the PublishTimeout value.
If your publishing client has a configurable connection timeout, set its value greater than the PublishTimeout value.
```

Additional information

Flash Media Server only allows one client publisher of a live stream to each application instance. It rejects any client that tries to publish an existing live stream and return a NetStream.Publish.BadName status to that client. Due to socket API limitations, it's possible that the server doesn't get notified that the original publisher was disconnected before it tries to republish the stream. The server honors the connection of the original stream publisher and blocks other publishing attempts for the same stream.

This work is licensed under a Creative Commons Attribution-Noncommercial-Share Alike 3.0 Unported License  Twitter™ and Facebook posts are not covered under the terms of Creative Commons.

Legal Notices   |   Online Privacy Policy

Comment: So i have to set timeout value? how can i do this with AS code?